# Monogame - How can I render FBX model on top of the camera

Tags: c#, windows-8, tablet, monogame

I am developing windows 8 tablet application with Monogame, Xaml, C#. I want to display the camera preview on the whole tablet screen and also render the FBX 3D model on the top of the camera so user can see the 3D model along with the camera preview behind it.

Is that possible?